# Website shows background img only on ios even though there is none specified?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I have a problem with my responsive page, which is based on Wordpress.
On the website and on the iOS emulator (on all I found from ipadpeek to mobilizer) the page titles appear just perfectly fine.
On my real Iphone + Ipad (in private mode) there is a background showing: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12178559/Foto.png
I know this was the standard setting on the beginning (showed on desktop too) but I deactivated it. I know the background picture name (stripes.png) and removed them from all css files where I could find it, but it was still there on ios.

How can I remove it? I really dont know what the problem could be anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You should delete your browser cache.

> Your iPad's cache is temporary storage space on your device where
>   recently viewed Web pages are held. Cache allows Safari to quickly
>   load a previously visited page without having to reload the entire
>   page and its images from the Web server on subsequent visits.
>
> Cache: More properly referred to as the webcache, Cache is all the
>   webpages you visit and most of the assets needed to build those
>   webpages. Caches help pages that you’ve visited before load more
>   quickly.

Do it like this:

1. Select 'Safari' in the Settings App
2. Click 'Clear Cookies and Data' (this also contains the cached pages)

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it; there was a single css just for that property which I didnt see because I cant develop on the Ipad directly...